# Can't find the css for a focused/clicked button in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have this image below, it a button.

I've set the border-radius to 50% to make it round.
How can I either set the focus highlight around the button be round or not show it at all?

I can't seem to find the :focus or :clicked css in the Chrome begugger.

[image]

Here is the html

```
<button id="frontSave" type="button" class="btn btn-lg"><i id="cameraIconFront" class="fal fa-camera fa-2x"></i></button>
```

Comment: As far as I know you can't get `border-radius` to apply to `outline`, but if you need a highlight that does conform to the radius, you can use `box-shadow` instead.  It should be pretty easy to make it look just like the native outline.  If you have any followup questions, just @ me and I'll try to respond later tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd just override the user agent stylesheet and replace the default `outline` with a `border`

Cheers

```css
body {text-align:center}

button {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  border: transparent 3px solid;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: red 3px dotted;
}
```

```html
<button>FOCUS<br/>TEST</button>
```